# creating a python class that finds the slope and length of a line segment

Tags: python, class

I need to figure out how to create a class that finds the slope and length of a line segment and is passed two tuples that represent the endpoints as (x,y). My problem is when I try to create a segment object it says int object is not callable. Please help

```
class Segment():
    def __init__(self, tup1, tup2):
            self.x1 = tup1[0]
            self.x2 = tup2[0]
            self.y1 = tup1[1]
            self.y2 = tup2[1]
            self.slope = 0
            self.length = 0

    def length(self):
            self.length = math.sqrt((y2-y1)**(2+(x2-x1)**2))
            print(self.length)

    def slope(self):
            self.slope = ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))
            print(self.slope)
```

Comment: can you show us how you're trying to "create a segment object"?

Comment: Also show the full traceback of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're overwriting your `self.length` method with `0` in your constructor. So when you try to call `s.length()`, it's actually trying to call `0()` because you assign `self.length = 0`.

You should probably do something like this instead (note I prefix every x and y value with `self` so it uses the attribute value of the instance):

```
class Segment():
    def __init__(self, tup1, tup2):
        self.x1 = tup1[0]
        self.x2 = tup2[0]
        self.y1 = tup1[1]
        self.y2 = tup2[1]

        self.length = math.sqrt((self.y2-self.y1)**(2+(self.x2-self.x1)**2))
        self.slope = ((self.y2-self.y1)/(self.x2-self.x1))
```

and then you can access the `length` and `slope` properties by simply accessing the instance attributes:

```
>>> s = Segment((1,2),(3,4))
>>> s.length
8.0
>>> s.slope
1
```

(it's also worth noting that your `length` function isn't quite correct, but I'll leave that fix up to you!)

Comment: @zackmusgrave awesome! consider upvoting and accepting if this helped you! [What to do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have same name for attribute and method. If you want to access the length like `instance.length` instead of `instance.length()` just change the method

```
def length(self):
    self.length = math.sqrt((y2-y1)**(2+(x2-x1)**2))
    print(self.length)
```

to

```
@property
def length(self):
    return math.sqrt((self.y2 - self.y1)**2 + (self.x2 - self.x1)**2)
```

Answer (score -1):

In the that code:

```py
class Segment():
    def __init__(self, tup1, tup2):
            self.x1 = tup1[0]
            self.x2 = tup2[0]
            self.y1 = tup1[1]
            self.y2 = tup2[1]
            self.slope = 0 ### Here
            self.length = 0 ### And here
```

You are making lenght variable of instance of Segment class equal to 0 (an int), and slope variable to 0. So now for example:

```py
line = Segment((0,0),(1,1))
line.lenght # 0
line.slope # 0
```

line.lenght and line.slope not an function anymore for line variable. They are int. And ints are not callable. You must change name of your functions or variables. Also change `x` and `y` variables in yor `lenght` and `slope` functions by self.x1 , self.y1 etc. Try that:

```py
class Segment():
    def __init__(self, tup1, tup2):
            self.x1 = tup1[0]
            self.x2 = tup2[0]
            self.y1 = tup1[1]
            self.y2 = tup2[1]
            self.slope = 0
            self.length = 0

    def Length(self):
            self.length = math.sqrt((self.y2-self.y1)**(2+(self.x2-self.x1)**2))
            print(self.length)

    def Slope(self):
            self.slope = ((self.y2-self.y1)/(self.x2-self.x1))
            print(self.slope)
```

But if you want a better code, I will give you two way.
If position of lines will not change, use that:

```py
class Segment():
    def __init__(self, tup1, tup2):
            self.x1 = tup1[0]
            self.x2 = tup2[0]
            self.y1 = tup1[1]
            self.y2 = tup2[1]
            self.length = math.sqrt((self.y2-self.y1)**(2+(self.x2-self.x1)**2)) 
            self.slope = ((self.y2-self.y1)/(self.x2-self.x1))
```

If position of lines may change, use that:

```py
class Segment():
    def __init__(self, tup1, tup2):
        self.set_points(tup1,tup2)

    def set_points(self,tup1,tup2):
        self._x1 = tup1[0]
        self._x2 = tup2[0]
        self._y1 = tup1[1]
        self._y2 = tup2[1]
        self.length = math.sqrt((self._y2-self._y1)**(2+(self._x2-self._x1)**2)) 
        self.slope = ((self._y2-self._y1)/(self._x2-self._x1))
```

And I think your Lenght function is not true. You may replace your Lenght function with that:

```py
def Length(self):
        return math.sqrt((self.x1+self.x2)**2+(self.y1+self.y2)**2)
```

Comment: this has to recompute the length every time, that seems pretty inefficient to me considering the points of the segment don't change

Comment: I said that if points of line may change, that is better. And there is no obstacle in code to change any  ```x``` or  ```y``` value of line. If points of segment will not change, we dont need methods anymore, we can use they as attributes.

Comment: not my downvote, but downvoting my (correct) answer is no way to respond, even if it was

Comment: I am sorry for downvoting your answer.